# Copy user profile of windows 7 current user using batch script

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I'm novice to batch scripting. Searched a lot in last 24 hrs to find a solution of copying user profile from windows 7 registry HKEY to a flash drive..
FYI I'm planning to run the script from a folder in my pc..
Help or suggestion or complete code appreciated..
Thank you in advance for your help guys.

Comment: Are you trying to copy a registry key? Which HKEY is it? If not, what are you using the registry for to get the userprofile?

Comment: I'm afraid I could make you understand my query. Or I don't understand what you mean. All that I'm trying to copy the user profile of windows 7 in a flash drive via batch script. Thanks again for any help.

Comment: Ok, hopefully my answer will show you how :) but if it's nothing to do with the registry you should take that out of your question, it makes it very confusing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the current userprofile by using (`E:` being your flash drive)

```
xcopy %userprofile% E:\ /e
```

Or if you want one that your not using you can use

```
xcopy C:\Users\UserToCopy E:\ /e
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Can you tell me what's wrong with this code.. In fact I've used the xcopy command but showing no files copied.. @echo off
title TITLE
xcopy %userprofile% E:\
pause
goto eof

Comment: Does it give you any errors? Try quoting the path incase it has spaces `"%userprofile%"`.

Comment: No its showing 0 Files copied.. Do I need to start the HKEY current user? If yes plz let me know how may I do it?

Comment: I just realised I missed the `/e` switch, try my updated answer :)

Comment: Well. Thanks. Its working.. But Its copying thousands of files like .dat etc for the user... All that I want is to copy the contact information only.. Is it possible? Thank you again for the help..

Comment: Good, what kind of info do you want? Do they all have the same file ext or something in common?

Comment: Hi. I were able to import the requested feature.. Is it possible to give me your contact here... I'd like to email you my requirement ie what I'm upto.. BTW can you tell me if its possible to email the file that I just copied from batch?